# File not found Exception when trying to open android SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following code as a DataBaseHelper in an android aplication:

```
    public class DbUtils {

    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.project.skcompanion/databases/";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "basesh.sqlite";



    public static void createDatabaseIfNotExists(Context context) throws IOException {
        Log.d("check1", "check1");
        boolean createDb = false;

        File dbDir = new File(DB_PATH);

        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

        if (!dbDir.exists()) {
            dbDir.mkdir();
            createDb = true;
        }
        else if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            createDb = true;
        }
        else {
            // Check that we have the latest version of the db
            boolean doUpgrade = false;

            if (doUpgrade) {
                dbFile.delete();
                createDb = true;
            }
        }
        Log.d("check2", "check2");
        if (createDb) {
            Log.d("check3", "check3");
            // Open your local db
            AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
            InputStream myInput = am.open(DB_NAME);
            Log.d("check4", "check4");
            // Open the empty db
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

    }



    public static SQLiteDatabase getStaticDb() {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

    }
```

But when the code tries to open the basesh.sqlite it sends a FileNotFoundException. I have my basesh.sqlite file in assets/databases. After some debugging, i think the problem is in this line.

```
InputStream myInput = am.open(DB_NAME);
```

But i have no idea why it isn't opening my file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you put the database file basesh.sqlite in `assets/databases`, which is wrong. context.getAssets().open("basesh.sqlite") looks into `assets` and it finds nothing. So you need to place it under `assets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open

```
InputStream myInput = am.open(DB_NAME);
```

Where as when you created database you create it on this path

```
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.project.skcompanion/databases/";
```

update your code to this

```
InputStream myInput = am.open(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need create file itself. Just create a database and the will be created.

Try this helper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name), null, Integer.valueOf(context.getString(R.string.database_version)));
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        createDb(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String[] versions = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.database_upgrade);
        for (int i = oldVersion; i < newVersion; i++) {
            String[] statements = versions[i - 1].split(";");
            for (String statement : statements) {
                db.execSQL(statement);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createDb(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.beginTransaction();
            String[] tables = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.database_tables);
            for (String table : tables) {
                db.execSQL(table);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.database_access_error));
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

and, for resources, including new version number of database, which update its structure:

```
<string name="database_version">2</string>

<string-array name="database_tables">
    <item>CREATE TABLE "COLLECT" (
        _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        DATE TEXT NOT NULL,
        SENT INTEGER, 
        OM REAL,
        CMSR REAL,
        DC REAL
        );</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="database_upgrade">
    <item>ALTER TABLE COLLECT ADD COLUMN SENT INTEGER;</item>
</string-array>
```

As you can see, when `database_version` was 1, sqliteHelper simply creates my `collect` table, as my example. If database already exists, like in example, and version number is now 2 or higher, sqliteHelper updates the db structure reading array `database_upgrade` iterating all of its items.